# Intuitive probability theory!?

Tags: probability-theory, intuition

Recently I saw something where someone had a paper with several lines on it and a needle. The length of the needle was the same as the distance between the lines. They then proceeded to say that when the needle is dropped, there is a  $\frac {2}{\pi}$ probability of the needle crossing one of the lines. As I have no idea how probability theory works, can anyone give some sort of intuition on why the probability is what it is?

Comment: This is Buffon's needle. Information on this can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon's_needle

Comment: And, here's an interactive applet for it: http://mste.illinois.edu/activity/buffon/

Comment: The [Buffon's noodle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_noodle) article gives a different, more intuitive, argument for the $2/\pi$ result (no calculus but an informal limit argument).

Comment: For an even more intuitive argument - based on @HenningMakholm 's reference above, see http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/piday/whypi.pdf .